# Heroku reCaptcha in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate reCaptcha to my node'js app. When I run the app locally everything's fine. But when I deploy the app to heroku, reCaptcha prints an error and is blocked for usage. If I open the console in browser I see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` from `https://google.com/...`

I guess that heroku blocks something, but just googling it didn't help.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it seems most likely that the domain of your Heroku app is not listed in your reCAPTCHA account, or your site-key is not set correctly.